# simple file upload in Rails doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I have an app on Rails3 and Ruby1.9. I want to upload a file. I have been trying a simple solution that I came across in several postings here.

Form

```
=form_for :upload, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
   = f.file_field :my_file
   = f.submit "Upload"
```

Controller

```
def file_upload
    path = File.join("public/", upload["my_file"].original_filename)
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload["my_file"].read) }
end
```

Routes

```
root :to => "pages#index"
resources :pages do
    collection {post :file_upload}
end
```

When I click 'Upload', I get no error, but the file is not being uploaded in the public dir. What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Show the controller action you're using to create that form, and also your routes.

Comment: Hi @smathy thank you for your response. I added the routes and also corrected the name of the form (:upload) to be consistent with the controller action (upload["my_file"]).

Comment: You're still not showing the controller method that `render`s the form. You're showing the controller method that's designed to receive the POST from the form, but I'm asking to see the controller method that's rendering the form.

Comment: I see, as far as I understand that is what I am missing. I haven't created a method to render the form. Could you please point me to an example?

Comment: You should probably start with the [Getting Started Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Comment: What is in your log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me ([reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)).

Controller: Changed the saving directory from public to public/uploads. Used Rails.root to do the join of the path.

```
def upload
    uploaded_io = params[:file]
    File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads',uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
         file.write(uploaded_io.read)
         respond_to do |format|
             format.html { redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'File was uploaded.') }
         end
     end
end
```

Form: Changed the form_for to form_tag

```
=form_tag({action: :upload}, multipart: true) do
    = file_field_tag 'file'
    = submit_tag 'Upload'
```

Routes:

```
root :to => "pages#index"
resources :pages do
    collection {post :upload}
end
```